# how to draw a line inside webview in android studio

Tags: android, webview, android-canvas, android-drawable

Below code gives me bitmap in my webview

```
Bitmap bitmap = bm;
String html="<html><body><img src='dicomFile' /></body></html>";

// Convert bitmap to Base64 encoded image for web
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
String imgageBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
String image = "data:image/png;base64," + imgageBase64;


// Use image for the img src parameter in your html and load to webview
html = html.replace("dicomFile", image);
imageView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
imageView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

I Tried drawing line inside webview using the below code but not working

```java
paint=new Paint();
canvas.drawLine(50,128, 300, 128, paint);
imageView.draw(canvas);
```

now i need to draw line inside this image.how is it possible?

Comment: Create a `Canvas` on the `Bitmap`, and use `Canvas#drawLine()`; e.g., `Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);`, `canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 50, 50, new Paint());`.

Comment: paint=new Paint();
 canvas.drawLine(50,128, 300, 128, paint);
 imageView.draw(canvas);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               This code was written by me for drawing line but not working

Comment: If you're saying that you've already attempted something and it's not working, then please [edit] your question to show us a [mcve].

Comment: @pooja, let us know what you did

Comment: That's not really a [mcve]. Anyway, assuming everything not shown is correct, drawing the `ImageView` after the line will cover that line. You need to do the `drawLine()` call after the `imageView.draw()` call.